# Convert Html To pdf using EVOPdf version 6.10

Tags: c#, pdf, evopdf

I am using Sample code for EvoPDf (version 6.10) for Converting Html to PDF in MVC. 
Code is shown below.

**byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);**

but it giving exception 
"*Could not start conversion. WinApi error code 216. Check 'evointernal.dat' file has execute permissions and that it exists near evohtmltopdf.dll or set the EvoInternalFileName property with the full path of the file*"

I have installed evoPDF 6.10 from Nuget Package manager.

Where it's files is availale, location is :  "Mvc\packages\EvoHtmlToPdf_x64.6.10\lib\net40"
here three files  "evohtmltopdf.dll", "evohtmltopdf", "evointernal.dat" available.

Even reference is also available for "evointernal.dat". but still getting exception.
Can please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Error 216 means that you are trying to use version of the library optimized for x64 in a 32-bit process. Please use the default generic version which works both in 32-bit and 64-bit environments.